# ORA -00909 //sql statement ignored ...procedure created with compilation errors

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, procedure

```
create or replace procedure Pupdate(   
peno in emp.empno%type,  
psal in emp.sal%type,  
pcomm in emp.comm%type)  
IS   
BEGIN  
UPDATE emp SET sal=sal+psal, comm=NVL(comm)+pcomm WHERE empno=peno;  
END Pupdate;  
/
```

The stored procedure takes the sal and comm from user and updates it into the emp table.
[image]

Comment: Please [avoid screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, what is unclear in the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 create or replace procedure Pupdate(   
peno in emp.empno%type,  
psal in emp.sal%type,  
pcomm in emp.comm%type)  
IS   
BEGIN  
UPDATE emp SET sal=sal+psal, comm=NVL(comm,0)+nvl(pcomm,0) WHERE empno=peno;  
END Pupdate;  
/
```

Just try this. NVL will be like NVL(column_name,value_if_null).

Answer (score 2):

`NVL()` takes two arguments, but I prefer ANSI standard `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE emp
    SET sal=sal + psal,
        comm = COALESCE(comm, 0) + COALESCE(pcomm, 0)
WHERE empno = peno;
```